# Volterra Operator on Sobolev Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory

I stumpled over the following result in a script:

Let $1 \leq p < \infty$ and $f \in L_p[a,b]$. Define the Volterra operator as $$Vf(t) = \int_a^t f(s) ds.$$
Then we have $Vf \in W^{1, p}[a,b]$ and $(Vf)' = f$.

Now there is given a hint: It is sufficient to consider the case $p = 1$ and $f \in C^1[a,b]$.

I could prove the statement for $p = 1$ and $f \in C^1[a,b]$ but I don't quite get why that should be sufficient.

I would be grateful for your advice :)

Comment: Your start is wrong. It does not justify only considering $ p=1$ since this would only show $ Vf $ is in the Sobolev space with p=1

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. I must have overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate any function in the Lebesgue space arbitrarily well by a differentiable function.

Taking a converging sequence of such approximating functions you can show that $ Vf_n $ is Cauchy in the Sobolev space,  hence has a limit in the Sobolev space. Since $ V $ is continuous as operator into the Lebesgue space the Sobolev limit equals $ Vf $

Comment: Would you mind to write it down a little more detailed? I got some problems deciding which norms are used at which point.

Comment: The norms are those of the spaces I mention at each point. But all the better if you're not sure, then you can figure it out yourself and have more of a learning experience. If you have a specific question I can get more specific too though

Comment: One question I have is the following: How can I approximate any function in the Lebesgue space arbitrarily well by a differentiable function? I know that I can approximate every $f \in L_2[a,b]$ by functions out of $C^\infty_0[a,b]$. But this result is new to me.

Comment: But functions in your space are in particular in $C^1$. So the result you mention is actually stronger than what we need. (Except the same thing holds not only for $L^2$ but for all $L^p$. )

Comment: Oh, I'm blind. Thanks, now I got it :)